# Combobox not changing when using next and back command buttons in Access

Tags: ms-access, button, combobox

When I select a value from the combobox, the correct record comes up, but when I use navigation buttons, the value in the combobox does not change; however, the records do change with the navigation buttons.

I've googled this for an hour and can't find solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown what you have done so far. So, I am just guessing. I assume that the ComboBox is unbound and is used solely for navigation.

Navigation buttons and ComboBox are not linked in any way. If you want to synchronize the ComboBox with the record you are navigating to, you can use the `OnCurrent` event (and I assume that you have done the `AfterUpdate` thing or something equivalent already):

```vb
Private Sub Combo3_AfterUpdate()
    ' Navigate using the ComboBox
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "UserID=" & Combo3.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    'Navigate using the navigation buttons
    Combo3.Value = UserID
End Sub
```